# What is the optimal Bitcoin Core 0.17 settings in bitcoin.conf settings for running a full node with a very beefy system?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf, cache

Is there an optimal bitcoin.conf setting file I should use when running a bitcoin core full node? I have a very beefy system with 16 core processor, 32gb ram, and nvme hard drive. I wan't to be able to dedicated as much resources as needed for the full node. I'm also running other nodes too, but would like to know what are the optimal settings in bitcoin.conf file.

I just learned about dbcache and this speeds up --reindex and would've been great if I had this setting in my bitcoin.conf file. Now I'm wondering what are some other optimal settings I should be putting in my bitcoin.conf file?

Comment: If you have problems with disk space, and you don’t want to download the entire 1.2 giga (I believe as of today ) so you can run it in prune mode.

Comment: even with prune mode, you still need to fully sync the blockchain first if I'm correct. what is the prune flag btw?

Comment: Command-line arguments @ https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Answer (score 3):

dbcache is the only significant performance influencing option.  Performance may be improved somewhat by increasing receive and send buffer sizes.

You don't specify exactly what application's you're concerned with speeding up.  To lower block reception latency you could connect to matt's public fibre network. See http://bitcoinfibre.org/public-network.html