# Bitcoin core initially downloads IBD quite fast , then it slows down a lot , What could be the reason?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am trying to setup a bitcoin node , ran bitcoin core and it started the download process quite fast ETA 18 hours , gradually the speed decreases .
When I started download it showed like 17 hours ETA, and this continued for around 2-3 hours.
**

```
Progress Increase Per Hour : 5.5 % 
Estimated time left until synced : 17 hours
```

**

after 2 - 3 hours , the progress starts going down .

After 5 hours

**

```
Progress Increase Per Hour : 0.71 % 
Estimated time left until synced : 5 days
```

**

I have enough empty hard disk around 200 GB free, RAM is also 4 GB .

I stopped the download , renamed the Bitcoin download folder and started download again fresh.

Same issue happened , initially the speed remains high but gradually after around 40 GB of download it starts going down drastically .

My configuration are

```
Prune block storage to : 2 GB
Size of database cache : 2048 MB
Number of script verification threads : 0
```

Is there a bug in bitcoin-core or is it an expected behavior ?  What can I do to speed it up ?

Answer (score 0):

> Progress Increase Per Hour : 5.5 %
> Estimated time left until synced : 17 hours

This estimate is based on samples: [src/qt/modaloverlay.cpp#L107](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/03826aecc56c5c5c76570805897c2ddf92e11ab6/src/qt/modaloverlay.cpp#L107)

It will keep changing and some blocks will be synced faster compared to others.

> Is there a bug in bitcoin-core or is it an expected behavior ?

Doesn't look like a bug. Maybe estimate logic can be improved or users can look at the number of blocks left to be synced.

> What can I do to speed it up ?

- Increase RAM and [dbcache](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/80254/)
- Increase number of threads or CPU/cores that are used for script verification