# Time needed for Bitcoin core synchronization

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I had put on the process of synchronization on **BITCOIN CORE** and it has been around **2years** since I had started the process and still its not completed, therefore now I would like to put some questions in front of you related to this

- Can I speed up this process of synchronization?
- Its done around 85%, how long it can take (it took 2 month to increase 5%)
- Can I cancel the synchronizing in between without affecting my bitcoins
- Can I send some bitcoins to another wallet while the process is on?
- Do the process of synchronizing time, depend on how much bitcoins are in wallet
- Showing me last block time ***"FEBRUARY 2021"*** and today is **OCTOBER** isn't it taking too long? or its normal?

*Currently I am facing very bad financial condition as by mistake I have put up synchronizing all the bitcoins at one time due to which all bitcoins are not blocked in the process and now I don't have money, your every answer would give peace to my heart, please help!*

Comment: You keep mentioning "Bitcore" as well next to Bitcoin Core. Is it possible that you downloaded malware that pretends to be Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I speed up this process of synchronization?

Things that can help in speeding up sync: RAM, dbcache and threads

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/107960/

> Its done around 85%, how long it can take (it took 2 month to increase 5%)

Its difficult to predict this but should not take more than few days

> Can I cancel the synchronizing in between without affecting my bitcoins

Sync progress will not affect private keys and wallets. You can close Bitcoin Core in between and it will resume from this block on next restart.

> Can I send some bitcoins to another wallet while the process is on?

If you see confirmed balance in wallet it can be used.

> Do the process of synchronizing time, depend on how much bitcoins are in wallet

No

> Showing me last block time "FEBRUARY 2021" and today is OCTOBER isn't it taking too long? or its normal?

It can take long sometimes. Difficult to say anything without logs.

Comment: Thank you very much Prayank, but just one more question where would I find "CONFIRMED BALANCE" in BITCORE?

Comment: [`getbalances`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/getbalances/)

Comment: I had one more question about this process i.e. can I stop the process of synchronisation in middle and make available (as I want to sell all the BTC now) all the BTC as **it's taking lot of time**, in that case would it affect my BTC, would I loose BTC while doing this process?